# Select DOMRange to modify / add the content in the existing WebView

Tags: cocoa, macos, uiwebview, webview

My requirement is like that, 
I have a WebView control in my view 
i will be getting data from some other source and need to display in the WebView, it could be an image, or any other Markup data,

As i know to insert the content programmatically, i should use the method below,

```
[pWebView replaceSelectionWithMarkupString:@"<html><body><p>Hi there </p></br></body></html>”];
```

Kind Regards
Rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WebView Insert / Modify Content dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311298/webview-insert-modify-content-dynamically)

Solved the way suggested in above answer